# Cannot save to geometry field from app deployed in Glassfish to Postgres13 with Postgis3.1.7

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, glassfish-5

I have this weird issue where I cannot read or write to geometry fields in my Database.
`INSERT INTO digital_addresses(gps_coordinates, digital_address) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326), ?)` fails with the error:

```
exception in get getOrSaveDigitalAddress. Reason: ERROR: function st_makepoint(real, real) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 233
```

I know postgis is installed correctly because I am able to execute same query from pgAdmin.

I have tried putting `postgis-geometry-2.5.1.jar`, `postgis-jdbc-2.5.0.jar` and                      `postgresql-42.2.25.jar` in different permutations and different versions into `{domain_dir}/domain1/lib/ext` still the issue persists.

select select postgis_full_version():

```
POSTGIS="3.1.7 aafe1ff" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.9.2-CAPI-1.14.3" PROJ="8.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.7" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong or what versions of postgressql and postgis should work for my setup.

Thanks!

Comment: so i partially figured a solution. it works if I select the resource_type as `javax.sql.Driver` and choose Vendor `Postgres`. If still fails if I attempt to use a datasource configuration instead. Not sure what is happening here tbh.

Answer (score 0):

If gps_coordinates field type is GEOMETRY try this one:
INSERT INTO digital_addresses (gps_coordinates, digital_address) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.064544 40.28787)',4326)), ?)